# Mapping using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I try mapp this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE AHQ.ReportConfigurationAttribute (
    IdReportConfiguration integer NOT NULL,
    IdAttribute integer NOT NULL,
    [Order] integer NOT NULL,
    [Type] integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ReportConfiguration_Attribute PRIMARY KEY (IdReportConfiguration, IdAttribute)
);
```

and,

```
 Schema("AHQ");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.IdReportConfiguration)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.IdAttribute);
        Map(a => a.Order);
        Map(a => a.Type).CustomType<ReportConfigurationAttribute.ReportConfigurationAttributeType>();
```

But

```
NHibernate.MappingException : No persister
```

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using fluent configuration? If so please also post the code for this.

Check that your mapping classes are public.

Comment: hi UpTheCreek, you are right, I forget to put my class like public.